# How to use the OTSU Threshold in opencv - input source

Tags: c++, opencv

I understand that this is the command to use otsu in opencv:

`cvThreshold(src, dst, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);`

However, I don't understand what that src and dst is, explained on the opencv website as:

input array (single-channel, 8-bit or 32-bit floating point).

What is an 8-bit or 32-bit floating point, single channel array?

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold

Comment: That would be your image...

Comment: src is the source image, so your input image (must be grayscale).
dst is where the thresholded image will be created, so that is the destination and the image that you want to get. That (dst) normally may be just a cv::Mat variable without any pixel data (size/type) allocated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Single channel means graysclale. 8 bits means unsigned char (CV_8U in OpenCV). 32bit means float (CV_32F in OpenCV)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was getting the image in the right format but I found at least two ways:

1. `CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("picture.png"); 
   IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);`

2.
`IplImage* frame = cvLoadImage("picture.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`

I am also under the impression that the picture needs to be grey scaled first, not sure how to do that for the first option though. Anyway, for src and dst these work.

Comment: You can use `cvCvtColor` to convert `frame` to grayscale.